# How can i overcome the error while installing VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to debug the code in VSCode so, whenever I try to install VSCode in my system it showing like an error occurred while trying to rename a file in the destination directory

[image]

Comment: Have you tried disabling antivirus or windows defender? or maybe try running as admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem which is stopping installation at extensionHostProcess.js is solved by disabling the antivirus at the particular file or the particular folder where this js file is going to settle down or you can disable antivirus for a certain time until the installation complete.

Comment: After trying everything this was the answer for me all along!